# Python Script that takes in Linux Commands to return Server Health

Tags: python, linux, health-check

For my job, I'm developing a small script that users can run to essentially do a check of log files for errors. I'm familiar with both Python and cmd prompts but not running one inside the other.

I read around quite a bit but can't really find the best process for this. Many seem a bit more complex for my intentions.

Ideally what I want to build is a program that follows this process:

For all dirs in host:

1. cd into directory then grep log file for a certain string

```
 -print errors

 -return back to a dir
```

2. cd into directory:

```
df -h
```

My personal preference would be to perform like so:

```
def myFirstCheck():
    file_result = cat a/b/c/LogFile.log | awk /ERROR\|/FATAL\
    file0_result = cat a/b/c/LogFile2.log | awk /ERROR\|/FATAL\
    return file_result, file0_result
    
def mySecondCheck():
    print('Server 2 check:')
    file2_result = cat d/e/f/LogFile3.log | awk /ERROR\|/FATAL\
    file3_result = cat d/e/f/LogFile4.log | awk /ERROR\|/FATAL\
    return file2_result, file3_result

file_result, file0_result = myFirstCheck()
print('Server 1 check:')
print('df -h') #I want this to return the output from cmd 'df -h'
print(file_result)
print(file0_result)

file2_result, file3_result = mySecondCheck()
print('Server 2 check:')
print('df -h') #I want this to return the output from cmd 'df -h'
print(file2_result)
print(file3_result)

#exit
```

I know this is widely inefficient and may be a `simple` way of thinking for something that may be a bit more complex. I just want to see if there's any helpful discussion from those with previous experience trying to do the similar thing.

Comment: To run the command into Python, Look into Python's `subprocess.check_output` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output. 

To run the remote commands you could simply use something like `ssh user@machine -c 'df -h'` for example. Look into setting password-less ssh access with `.ssh/autorized_keys`. Hope that helps

Comment: @LeandroN. thanks for this. I will certainly look into it deeper. I should have properly clarified that the user will have already ssh'd into the box and will just want to run the script to get an output and overall view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to do alot of things with the cmd, but you can do it pythonicly.

you can read file like this:

```py
with open("/path/to/log/file", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
error_lines = [line for line in data.splitlines() if "ERROR" in line]
```

secondly, for the df -h, you can simple do it as:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("df -h")
```

or if you want to do it pythonic and know the disks path you can do it as:

```py
import psutil
hdd = psutil.disk_usage('/')
```